# What is the difference between 'his eye' and 'him in the eye'?

Tags: grammar

There are two sentences like these.

1. The girl stared at his eye.
2. The girl stared at him in the eye.

What is the difference between the two expressions in meaning?

Answer (score 1):

As per @John's answer, #1 is a fairly unlikely statement. But it would always be understood to mean there was something unusual about his eye, and she was (probably, *rudely*) staring/gawping at it.

But #2 simply isn't idiomatically credible with ***at*** - and although you might occasionally come across [*She stared him in the eye*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stared%20him%20in%20the%20eye%2Clooked%20him%20in%20the%20eye&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstared%20him%20in%20the%20eye%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clooked%20him%20in%20the%20eye%3B%2Cc0), the idiomatic standard is *She **looked** him in the eye*, as you can see from that NGram. For all practical purposes they both mean the same (she looked directly and intently *into his eyes*, not just *at his face*).

So even if you might *think* you want the "looking **intently**" connotations of ***stare*** rather than the more general-purpose ***look***, it's not really a good idea to couple this with ***in the eye***. That's because failure to use standard phrasing will probably simply distract readers, rather than make them pay attention to your attempt to be more "precise".

Note that *to look someone in the eye* nearly always implies being *honest* and/or *without fear or shame.*

Comment: The "stared at his eye" wants to be completed with "which lay on the floor after it fell out of his head".  ;)

Comment: @Catija: You certainly have a vivid imagination! When I wrote "something unusual about his eye" I was thinking he might just have a black eye or something. My most exotic "something" was thinking an optician might have just applied dilating drops to one eye (to make it easier to look for cataracts, for example). My 95-year-old father had that done recently, and I gotta say it looks *really* weird. Not as weird as an eye actually falling right out, but definitely enough to make everyone stare at it!

Answer (score 0):

#1 means that there could be something wrong with his eye, and she was staring at it.

#2 means that she was staring at *him* - his mind, his being, his self - 'through' his eye(s).

Note that the second version is usually plural "eyes" - even though she may only be looking at one of them.